# if else if - not returning desired image

Tags: php

Trying to display a corresponding image based on $enrollment_points equalling one of 3 values; 1000, 750 or 500.

With $enrollment_points setup successfully in a vars.php file, it only returns/displays the first image from the if statement,  even though $enrollment_points = 750. It does not seem to get past the if statement or evaluate the integer from the $enrollment_points string.

I can't figure out why?

thanks in advance

```
<?php

if ($enrollment_points = "1000") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/1000_enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";

} elseif ($enrollment_points = "750") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/750_enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";

} elseif ($enrollment_points = "500") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/500_enrollment2_700x600_.png' alt='' />";

} else {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";
}

?>
```

i expect the corresponding image file to be displayed based on the value of $enrollment_points.

Comment: As a side note, a switch case might make your code a little cleaner to read. Here's a simple example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Answer (score 2):

To compare for equality, you should use == and not =

So change it to

```
if ($enrollment_points == "1000") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/1000_enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";
```

EDIT:
For your question about == or ===. == compares value only. === compares the value AND type. See below:

```
1 === 1: true
1 == 1: true
1 === "1": false // 1 is an integer, "1" is a string
1 == "1": true // type is ignored, so true.
```

Comment: perfect yes thanks to All the exact right answer - thanks. I still cannot get the 3rd value, the 500, to display its image. Am I limited to only one elseif condition? the 1000 and  750 display correctly as well as any other number other than 500 that i setup in the var.php file

Comment: so i added === to the 500 value line and it worked - why??  do i need to use three when comparing more than two or is it a one for one thing ie. if i had 8 values i would have to use ======== ?

Comment: == checks for value only. === checks for value and type. But i am not sure why your variable works for === and not ==. Normally it is the other way around. That means "500" is a string. And 500 is integer, if you compare these 2 with ===, then you will get false returned. But it should always true when using ==.

Answer (score 1):

One "=" is use for assign value, Two "==" and three "===" use for compare.

```
<?php

if ($enrollment_points == "1000") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/1000_enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";

} elseif ($enrollment_points == "750") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/750_enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";

} elseif ($enrollment_points == "500") {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/500_enrollment2_700x600_.png' alt='' />";

} else {
echo "<img src='../1_LandingPage_Content/images/offers/enrollment_700x600_.png' alt='' />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variables inside your if statement rather than comparing:

```
 if($enrollment_points = "750")
```

change to:

```
 if($enrollment_points == "750")
```

Remember, one "=" for setting, two or three for comparing

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning the value of 1000 to $enrollment_points variable then yes thats the case but if you want them to equal, as in equality statement use the '==' sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use == for if statement, not =. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php